# AWS Lambda GO and image response broken

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

currently I'm trying to proxy images through a go lambda function from S3 backend.
basically i retrieve the image as []byte from S3 and try to pass it to the browser as image/png

```golang
imgData := repository.GetBinary(cType, cId, uuid)

    b64img := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(imgData)

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
        Body:       b64img,
        IsBase64Encoded: true,
        Headers: map[string]string{
            "Content-Type":              "image/png",
        },
    }, nil
```

I tried it as base64 encoded as well as not. The image won't be rendered.

When i do it without lambda as go server it works fine.

```golang
    lib.Init()
    // disable validation here
    lib.App.ValidateHeader = false
    b := repository.GetBinary(cType, cId, uuid)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")

    img := bytes.NewReader(b)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/png")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    io.Copy(w,img)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Did you enable binary support for your rest API? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html

Comment: @hephalump The problem is that the image is not visible. The content type is correct but somehow the data is broken

Comment: @Ngenator Yes it is set. But the API is a lambda_proxy.... You cannot say passthrough in the request integration

Comment: Client requests also need to include an `Accept` header that matches one of the binary content types you added to the API

Comment: Even with the Accept it doesn't work. :(
https://devapi.velten.cloud/v1/file/smoUserProfileImage/1/497a8f58-eb4c-11e9-b935-02f407d4a930/original

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after adding the `Content-Length` header:

```golang
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := png.Encode(buf, image); err != nil {
        return errorResponse(err)
    }

    b64img := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf.Bytes())

    return &events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
        Headers: map[string]string{
            "Content-Type":   "image/png",
            "Content-Length": fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(b64img)),
        },
        Body:            b64img,
        IsBase64Encoded: true,
    }, nil
```

Comment: Consider also adding `"Content-Disposition": fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", imagename),`
You might even need to escape imagename. See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.FileAttachment